# Best way to structure a widget with SVGs

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I am looking for a bit of wisdom from someone with a bit of experience working with SVGs. I am attempting to create a drag and drop widget using SVGs in HTML similar to Tetris (except you can move the blocks any which way). As of now, I have a canvas with a bunch of SVG's for each block:

- Canvas

  - SVG A
  - SVG B
  - SVG C
  - SVG D

Each SVG has its own event listeners so I can drag each block but I soon want to add grid-snapping and prevent overlapping. What would be the best way to structure my code? Should I re-structure my code to be one big SVG instead of a canvas and have each block be an element of the SVG? What would be the pros and cons of each direction?

[image]

Comment: Why SVG? If this design is all you want then do it with regular DIVs and CSS grid. If you do want drag/drop SVGs be sure to test early on tablets with ``touchmove`` events. And a mix of SVG objects in a CSS grid is an option too (I did Chess, Checkers and Ludo that way, SVG pieces on an HTML CSS grid board)

Comment: The above design is very over-simplified. The end product will actually be a more complicated version of https://www.elyah.io/workbench/lite. I think I am going to need to be able to manipulate the objects using a coordinate system (ex x = 3, y = 10) and I don't think that would work with DIVs and a CSS grid.

Comment: That site is all HTML and CSS Grid; only the draggable objects are SVG. You can do a lot with **overlaying** CSS grids to create fine-grained coordinate systems. With SVG (vector) or Canvas (pixels) you will have to write all positioning (down to the pixel) yourself. Challenge is going to be responsize display on other screensize/devices.. which are easier to tackle with HTML

Comment: I'll have to look into that. Do you have any pointers or references I can start with? If you write an answer (even if it's short) I'll give it to you and I'll vote to close this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three routes you can take

1. All HTML

   But you reply in the comments you have more complex SVG shapes
2. All SVG

   https://www.petercollingridge.co.uk/tutorials/svg/interactive/dragging/ is a good starting point.
   Challenge is sizing your 'canvas' on other devices, probably requires different viewBox settings on mobile or when desktop users resize the window
3. Mix

   Think a chessboard; your 'canvas' is one (or more stacked) CSS grids, The pieces are your SVGs

   I experimented with this on https://chessmeister.github.io  and in [Svelte ChessMeister](https://svelte.dev/repl/382ed83cd7954f60882bd03b04e49714?version=3.16.7)

   **ALL Proof of Concept code! Not meant to be educational. And I did not do touchmoves in this desktop version**

   It was mainly a modern Web Components proof-of-concept; but the concept is the same;  the **stacked** board layers are all CSS grids:

[image]

**3. Mix** - will be the easier approach **IMHO** because you can use all HTML5 capabilities, and you are not restrained to only SVG capabilities.

I eventually went with 100% Native Web Components instead of Svelte for my new venture; because the code needs to be maintainable and run for the next 25 JavaScript years. (I have yet to see a library or framework that lasts 25 years)

- Boardgames where the board is Chess-like I used HTML CSS Grid, and SVG only for pieces.
- I did [Catan](http://hexedland.com/catan.html) in 100% SVG (without Drag Drop!) because the layout was more difficult in HTML
- I did [Trivia](http://hexedland.com/trivia.html) 100% SVG for the board, but the (drag-drop) pieces are HTML (with SVG content)
  I did try 100% SVG drag-drop, but missed the HTML5 Web Components flexibility

Semantic HTML is important to me:

[image]

The Custom Elements API (aka Web Components) can only extend the HTMLElement; so you can not extend SVGElement.. that would be cool in the future.. but this is not on any horizon yet.

Oh, and one of your best friends will be:

- https://caniuse.com/?search=elementsfrompoint